# Box2D calculate distance in certain direction

Tags: c++, box2d

I'm writing simple AI genetic learning for a 2d car. To do so I need sensors surrounding my car so I can get distance to closest obstacle in every direction. (Picture 1)

Picture 1:[image]
I need every of the sensors V1,V2,...,V5 to return a value which is distance to the closest obstacle. Directions of vectors have to be fixed on car position. I've been looking for the solution, but every sensor in web is either circle shaped or returns if there was collision.

So far I have whole collision system, car steering and track coded. Now I need to get to the AI part and distance values are crucial to do so. Any solutions or tips? I'm new to Box2d and I don't feel comfortable using it yet :)

Thanks for Your help :)

Edit.1: https://github.com/elokhar/ai-cars - repo with my project. This is what I have for this moment.

Edit.2:

```
void Car::update()
{
    b2Vec2 angle = this->m_body->GetPosition();
    for (auto wheel : m_wheels)
    {
        wheel->updateDrive(rotation, speed);
    }



    b2RayCastInput input;
    input.p1 = m_body->GetPosition();
    input.p2 = m_body->GetLocalPoint(m_wheels[0]->getBody()->GetWorldCenter());
    input.maxFraction = 30;

    float closestFraction = 3.0; //start with end of line as p2
    b2Vec2 intersectionNormal(0, 0);
    for (b2Body* b = world->GetBodyList(); b; b = b->GetNext()) {
        for (b2Fixture* f = b->GetFixtureList(); f; f = f->GetNext()) {
            if (TODO) {
                b2RayCastOutput output;
                if (!f->RayCast(&output, input, 1))
                    continue;
                if (output.fraction < closestFraction) {
                    closestFraction = output.fraction;
                    intersectionNormal = output.normal;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    b2Vec2 intersectionPoint = input.p1 + closestFraction * (input.p2 - input.p1);

    printf("%f\n", closestFraction);
}
```

Okay. So I have this. It shows distance, but it shows distance to wheels of a car itself. I want in "TODO" to implement ignoring other wheels and car body for this ray cast. This is the last thing I need I suppose. :)

Comment: This looks like a [raycast](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/raycasting) - have you tried using rays for this purpose?

Comment: I have thought about it, but making them fixed to my car position isn't as trivial as I thought

Comment: It's not? Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: Instead of dumping your whole GitHub repository on us, you should post the relevant problematic piece of code that you have tried to use for fixing the rays to your car's position.

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 Sorry, edited.